# State not updating inside FormGroup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've created functional component using to render list of selects with menu items having data provided from external provider. The expected behavior is again render of selects list when select item would changed. I created state and initialized it, next mapped items from state and used state parameters to manage logic inside component, but... unfortunelly set state execution doesn't make any effect. How can I render component again after set state? My code is below:

```
 class TemplateMenuItem{
     constructor(index, displayName, menuItem, isSelected){
         this.index = index;
         this.displayName = displayName;
         this.menuItem = menuItem;
         this.isSelected = isSelected;
     }
  }

  export const SetTemplateVariables = (props) => {

   ...

   const [items, setItem] = React.useState(variablePlaceholders.map(
        (x, index) => new TemplateMenuItem(index, x.displayName, 0, false)
   ));

   const handleChange = (index, displayName, menuItem) => {
       let placeholderIndex = items.findIndex(x => x.index === index);
       items[placeholderIndex] = new TemplateMenuItem(index, displayName, menuItem, true);
       setItem(items);
   }

    return(
        <FormGroup>
            {items.map(({index, displayName}, placeholderIndex) =>
                <FormControl variant="outlined" className={styles.formControl}>
                    <Container>
                        <InputLabel id={`label-${index}`}>{displayName}</InputLabel>
                        <Select id={displayName}
                                className={styles.select}
                                labelId={`label-${index}`}
                                autoWidth={false}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                    handleChange(placeholderIndex, displayName, e.target.value)}
                                value={items[placeholderIndex].menuItem}>
                            {stepData.map((item, stepIndex) => <MenuItem value={stepIndex}>{item}</MenuItem>)}
                        </Select>
                    </Container>
            </FormControl>)}
        </FormGroup>
    );
```

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is state mutation. After you find the index and update and set a new element *at* that index, you update state with the same array reference from the current render cycle.

```
const handleChange = (index, displayName, menuItem) => {
  let placeholderIndex = items.findIndex(x => x.index === index);

  // state mutation!
  items[placeholderIndex] = new TemplateMenuItem(index, displayName, menuItem, true);
  // save existing reference back in state!
  setItem(items);
}
```

React needs a new array reference to correctly pick up the state update. This is trivial to do with array::map. Map the items into a new array and use the second parameter for the current index to match the passed index to map a new `TemplateMenuItem`.

```
const handleChange = (index, displayName, menuItem) => {
  setItem(items => items.map((item, i) => {
    if (i === index) {
      return new TemplateMenuItem(index, displayName, menuItem, true);
    }
    return item;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is amazing!